# minimumInteritemSpacing is adding some strange content at the end of collection view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to achieve horizontally scrolling collection view with only 1 line. As I found out the easiest way to achieve that is to prepare custom flow layout:

```
class CollectionViewLayoutHorizontal : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        //that enables self-sizing cells
        self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        //that one should ensure that only one line fits
        //using CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude aka CGFLOATMAX breaks collection view completely
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1000
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    }
}
```

All my cells are properly displayed - they are places next to each other at the middle of collection view even when they are much smaller.
But the problem is there is an extra empty space at the end (after last cell) that is the size of `minimumInteritemSpacing` which is something unexpected.

Does anyone solve that problem ?

[image: bug]

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but it still has no clear answer.

I ran into this exact same problem just recently using Swift 4.2 on iOS 12. After some investigations I found out that if you set the `minimumLineSpacing` to anything less than its default value (i.e. `10`) then flow layout will add this difference multiplied by (number of items - 1) as an extra space to the end of the collection view. (Looks like the total `contentSize` is calculated with the default value regardless?)

Anyway I was able to solve this by setting the `minimumInteritemSpacing` to be the same value as `minimumLineSpacing`, which was `2` for both in my case.

I know it doesn't make any sense, since my collection view is a one-line with horizontally scrolling collection view flow layout, so `minimumInteritemSpacing` should have no effect in laying out the items, but apparently it does and this does the trick of removing the extra space at the end.

Comment: 2021, Xcode 13.1, iOS 15.0 and this issue is still relevant. Fortunately, this solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Set `minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` (or some smaller value that fits to your collection design at end of scroll), if you do not need to set trailing space inside collection view.

For a vertically scrolling grid, `minimumInteritemSpacing` value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same row.

For a horizontally scrolling grid, `minimumInteritemSpacing` value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same column.

`minimumInteritemSpacing` spacing is used to compute how many items can fit in a single line, but after the number of items is determined, the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted upward.

For more, see Apple Developer Document: [minimumInteritemSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617706-minimuminteritemspacing)

Comment: There is a problem when I do that - items won't be align in one line :(
Check here: http://pasteboard.co/MVOX44fyc.png

Comment: The reason I started to play with that value, is to force items despite of their size, to be layout in a line.

Comment: For horizontal scroll direction, general all cells, align to same line and minimumInterItem space also set horizontal distance between cell & trailing inner side of collectionview, so It may not disturb horizontal alignment of your cell. However you are facing a problem with that.. Can you please share more details about your collection view code & screen shot if interim space = 0

Comment: Here is screenshot - collection view is 130 height,items are 20 pixels:

http://pasteboard.co/MVOX44fyc.png

This is when I get rid on spacing values

Comment: Your problem may have a relation with collection view's flowlayout delegate method.. please share it's code, if you've implemented.

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize

Comment: Nope it's not done this way. I'm using self-sizing cells and preferredLayoutAttributesFitting that calls systemLayoutSizeFitting.
But it's not a problem. It works same way even if I use fixed item sizes...

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this by:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGSizeMake(70, 60);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

And set the flow layout of the collection view:

```
-(void)setCollectionViewLayout {

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = 5;

[yourCollectionview setCollectionViewLayout:flow];
```

}

Note : my collection view has constant height.

Comment: That won't place all my times in one line - it will align them as here http://pasteboard.co/MVOX44fyc.png

Answer (score 1):

Solution for collectionViewLayout
It's caused by the width/height of the group being set as absolute / fractional. Make the scrolling side as estimated.

```
    NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1.0), 
                           heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
```